# Jade And EJS For Node

Tags: node.js, pug, ejs

Is there a way I can use ejs and jade(I like both EJS and Jade and cannot decide which to use):

```
div
   <% for(var i = 0; i<things.length; i++){ %>
        <% = things[i] %>
        span!=things[i] + "  Hi"
   <% } %>
```

And would the best way to do this to run it through jade then ejs?

Thanks,
Ari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div
    each thing in things
        != thing
        span!= thing + "   Hi"
```

Alternative:

```
div
    - for(var i = 0; i < things.length; i++){
        != things[i]
        span!= things[i] + "   Hi"
    - }
```

I would suggest using jade. I think that it's far more comfortable and you can generate much html with very little jade code.

Comment: Please view the revised question

Comment: @AriPorad please see updated answer. I'm pretty sure that jade is better choice :)